# Derivative a interaction term in GAM Model

Tags: r, spline, non-linear-regression, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to model an estimation of the price elasticity of demand for each customer using GAM model, a model like this:

```latex
\ln D = \ln P + \ln P \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{20} f(X_i) 
PED = \frac{\partial \ln D {\partial \ln P} = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^{20} f(X_i)
```

https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?$$&space;\ln&space;D&space;=\ln&space;P&space;+&space;\ln&space;P&space;\cdot&space;\sum_{i=1}^{20}&space;f(X_i)\\PED&space;=&space;\frac{\partial&space;\ln&space;D}{\partial&space;\ln&space;P}&space;=&space;1&space;+&space;&space;\sum_{i=1}^{20}&space;f(X_i)

where $D$ is Demand, $P$ is rate, PED is price elasticity of demand and $X_i$ is a set of customer's variable.

Since $PED$ is not observable, i want to estimate PED from the model created for log demand using gam model, but I have trying some difficulty in how to estimate that way.

I tried to get the each splines to calculate PED, but i failed. I know there is a package called *gratia* with derivatives function, but i dont understand how to use it to calculate ped.

Once the model to estimate demand is created, I will need to estimate the price elasticity of demand for each customer, but for these customers I don't have the rate variable, only the 20 personal variables.

I read some links:

```
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495775/first-derivative-of-fitted-gam-changes-according-to-specified-model-distribution

 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590167/how-can-i-calculate-a-derivative-of-a-global-smooth-and-group-level-smooths-with

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32013/what-is-the-mathematical-model-formula-corresponding-to-this-gam-model-fit-in-r
```

Really appreciate for any explanation, advices or other way to model my data.

Thanks

**EDIT**

What i've tried:

```r
#create the dataset
A <- sample(x = 0:1000, size = 5000, replace = TRUE)
B <- sample(x = 0:1000, size = 5000, replace = TRUE)
C <- sample(x = 0:1000, size = 5000, replace = TRUE)
D <- sample(x = 0:1000, size = 5000, replace = TRUE)
log.R <- log(rbeta(5000, 5,10)*10) #log rate
log.Y <- log(rgamma(5000, 10, 20)*10000) #log demand

mydata <- data.frame(A, B, C, D, log.R, log.Y)

#the model
model <- gam(log.Y ~ s(A, by=log.R) + s(B, by=log.R) + s(C, by=log.R) + s(D, by=log.R), data = mydata, method = "REML")

mfx <- marginaleffects(model, variables = "log.R", eps = 10^-5)

head(mfx)
```

mfx returns a 'dydx' column, is it the elasticity of my data used to model?

And when i will apply this model to newdata, i got an error:

```r
newdat = data.frame(A = 750, B = 500, C = 398, D = 740)

marginaleffects(model, variables = "log.R", eps = 10^-5, newdata= newdat, slope = 'dydx')

Error: There is no valid predictor variable. Please change the `variables` argument or supply a new data frame to the `newdata` argument.
```

What should I do?

Comment: You may find the {marginaleffects} package useful (disclaimer: I am the author). In particular, see these two vignettes on GAMs and Elasticity. Also make sure you read the "Getting Started" page: https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/gam.html https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/marginaleffects/articles/elasticity.html

Comment: thanks for helping me, i edited my post, could you see again, please? i am new in gam models, im learning. :)

Comment: There is no column called log.R in the dataset. This explains the error. The marginaleffects function computes the slope. It also allows you to compute elasticities. The documentation on the package is very extensive, and there is one very long vignette walking through what I mean by “slope” in addition to the ones I linked to above.

Comment: I understand what you said, but I want to estimate the elasticity and I don't have log.R in my new data nor log.D. Is there a way to estimate without the log.R? my goal is to estimate new customer elasticity from just a set of personal variables, so I'm deriving a generalized additive model with respect to log.R to get the right side of the equation in the image.